# Django User Editing, AbstractUser

Tags: django

We are trying to build endpoints to allow users to edit their own profiles from our front end and we've encountered a problem while trying to edit the "logged in user". This issue happens in django admin as well.

**All the rest of this post is specifically referring to the "user" in django admin. I have extended the user and built a custom admin.**

if we have 3 users, (imagine all three are super users/is_staff for now). Logged in user 1, I can edit users 2 and 3, but when I go to edit user 1 (logged in user), the message says it was updated but the database does not change.

If I then login as user 2 and update user 1, I can update user 1 but not user 2 as the logged in user.

This same behavior happens on our endpoints with request.user. request.user can edit any user except for the logged in user.

**CODE**

**accounts/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_carrier = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_shipper = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_tracking = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

It is defined in settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

**accounts/admin.py**

```
CustomUser = get_user_model()


class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User


class AgentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Agent


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = CustomUser

    agent_fields = ('timezone', 'is_agent', 'is_customer', 'is_shipper', 'is_carrier', 'is_tracking')
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        ('Agent Info', {'fields': agent_fields}),
    )
    inlines = [
        AgentInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**MIGRATIONS 0001_initial.py**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('is_customer', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_agent', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_carrier', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_shipper', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
]
```

**Screenshots of my testing**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's the output of the UPDATE, you can see that first name is being saved as blank string. So maybe this is form related?

[image]

It's likely that when we added the custom user model we did something wrong as I believe it was added after the project creation.

Because of this i'm assuming the logged in user is maybe making a change to the wrong table in the DB. I'm not exactly sure how to identify this though, normally I would shell in but the original auth_user model is disabled from being imported because of our custom model.

Let me know if I can provide anymore context.

***UPDATE 1***

It looks like the update is actually working, then it's being immediately overwritten by the original data. See this screenshot, this happens on a single update. You can see an UPDATE statement with the last name having a value, then a second UPDATE with the original data.

[image]

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) surely would help.
[You can make django log all executed sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) ([example](https://www.neilwithdata.com/django-sql-logging)), this may hint you in the correct direction.

Just to make sure: Right after the update, `request.user` is not updated, you have to call [`refresh_from_db`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database) to see the update there – I guess you did that?

Comment: Could you add the code related to the editing of the users? If the code is using wrong tables, which I think it shouldn't, the logged-in user shouldn't also be able to update other users. Also, when you say that you get the message that the user was updated, do you get it on opening the user edit page or after clicking save? How do you determine that the user is not really updated?

Comment: I added some more code to show the admin.py that i'm referring to and some screenshots to show you how I'm testing this.

Comment: @He3lixxx, I was able to print out the SQL and something is funky because I'm trying to update the first name but the SQL is passing blank string instead of my value.

Comment: Added an update, the sql is showing an update then a duplicate update with the original data. Added a screenshot to show.

Comment: Check out [this gist on how to get a stacktrace of the line causing the query](https://gist.github.com/stantonk/5515473). I'd currently guess that for some reason, after your correct update, some code calls `request.user.save()`, which triggers the query that resets the user. (I haven't tested the gist, I just found it. I'd say if you find out where that query is caused you are likely able to fix it). Maybe some middleware is causing this. Which middleware do you have enabled?

Comment: middleware..... how did I not think of this. We have a middleware doing something on the request.user that is causing the overwrite. I commented it out and now it works perfectly.  @He3lixxx, do you want to turn that into an answer somehow and I can mark it correct?

1. The logging of sql queries was super crucial to finding this.
2. I didn't use the stacktrace but that could have helped a ton, i just looked at my middleware and commented out stuff I knew was custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl,dr: The update was done properly, but a middleware caused a `request.user.save()` (or similar), writing back the old values to the db.

---

Findings from the comments expanded into an answer:

It turns out the update query was executed just as expected, which matches the message "User was changed successfully". Enabling [logging of all sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#django-db-backends) allowed to confirm this.

However, right after the correct update query, there was another query resetting the user to its state before. Here, it helps to know that when the form is saved, it does not update the python object accessible via `request.user` (because it doesn't know that the updated user is `request.user`). It would only be updated if someone called [`refresh_from_db`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) on it.

Thus, I suspected something called `request.user.save()`, which would then store back the outdated state. This would match the queries we observed. But the django admin view should not do that. On the internet, there are some pages on how to get [stack traces together with the query log](https://gist.github.com/stantonk/5515473), which should allow to find out where the query is issued from.

However, even without the hassle of enabling the log, the culprit in this case could be identified to be some middleware. This can be easily tested by simply commenting out any (custom) middleware that is not essential.

Comment: This was the exact problem. I had a middleware that was calling request.user.save(). This resulted in a "double save" the second one being the original state of request.user.

Leaving everything in tact, I changed request.user.save() to request.user.save(update_fields=['<my field>']) and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably did initial migration before creating  **CUSTOM_USER**

---

Now you can delete all `migration files` and can run a fresh migration.

Comment: All of this has been in production for quite some time. I don't specifically remember, but I do remember that when this project was first built I did not understand migrations at all so it's very likely I did the custom user after the initial migration of the app. Are you saying:
1. Delete all migration files in the app
2. re run makemigrations
3. re run migrate

I think this will error so I'm assuming I just fake the migration?

Comment: This actually might be my best route, resetting the migrations on this specific app:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Comment: I went and looked at the very first migration file in the app, 0001 and it seems like I might have attempted to do it correctly, I can see creating the model and adding my custom fields

Comment: @KrisTryber , You had to set your CustomUser before initial migration . But, you did the opposite which Django doesn't suport . Now you can go through the answer  to find your solution .

Comment: Ya it sounds like I need to do like you said, delete all migrations and re run, but go through and do it for every app with dependency migrations as well

Comment: dependency stores in your virtual environment No need to migrate them .

Comment: Re creating the migration files would not actually allow me to ever run the migrate command unless I fake them. At that point it would do nothing though right? Sorry if I'm not understanding.

Comment: @G.SDash "But, you did the opposite which Django doesn't suport" How do you come to that conclusion? [Documentation on changing the UserModel after running the first migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). Also, could you explain how you would expect this to cause updates on all users to work except for the logged in user? I don't see how this could happen.